# Can you set a default run project in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I have two projects in Eclipse. Project A is basically a library project that's not intended to be run directly. Project B is an application that references Project A. While working on Project B I often tweak files in Project A and find myself pressing "run" while on those files, which tries to run Project A (which can't be run). Is there a way to set a default project in Eclipse so that when I press run project B will always run without prompting me about project A (FYI there is no run configuration for Project A).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can.Go to Window->Preferences->Run/Debug->Launching. In Launch operation select "Always launch the previously launched application"